# Why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process

I applied for a job 3 days ago and today I got an email at 3:00PM that said:

> [My name],
>
> Thank you for reaching out with regards to our opening. Is there a time later this week that we could touch bases and discuss the fit.

I responded 15 minutes later with:

> Hi [his name],
>
> How does tomorrow at 12:00PM sound?
>
> Thanks
>
> [My name]

I am concerned because the hiring manager hasn't gotten back to me yet.

Why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?

Comment: Does "for the entire day" mean between 3:15 when you sent the email and whenever the hiring manager left work?  So at most a couple of work hours?

Comment: One day is no time at all.  If you haven't heard back in a week, then you could email a reminder to the hiring manager.

Comment: Did it occur to you that you gave your employer absolutely no flexibility with respect to date and time? If you did that to me, unless you are an outstanding candidate, that's the last you hear from me.

Comment: I made an edit to remove some "tell me what to do" parts and focus on the answerable part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why hasn't the hiring manager gotten back to me?

"Later this week" to me implies... later in the week, not "tomorrow in less than  5 business hours from now."

Don't make the one option only 21 hours total - and only 5ish in the workday - after the initial email was sent. Most people in management positions get a ton of email and don't necessarily read every email immediately.

Also, never give someone only one option in a situation like this, especially if that option is in the middle of a common lunch hour. More options allows a better chance of connecting early and avoiding playing Go-Fish over the time.

What would work better is something like:

> Hi,
>
> I would love to! I am available at any of the following times:
>
> - Tuesday, 9am-12pm, 4:30pm - 6pm
> - Wednesday, 12pm-6pm
> - Friday, 3pm - 6pm
>
> Let me know if one of those times will work!

Comment: +1, could also phrase a range, such as "Monday morning" or "Wednesday afternoon".

Comment: @EdwinLambregts I think the biggest issue with that is "what does afternoon mean?" For some people who leave at 330, afternoon is "12-330" but for people who leave at 530 then it might be "12 - 530." Best to be specific (same with mornings).